# How do you show that branch cuts result in a single valued function for logarithmic branch points?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts, branch-points

I know the way that basically everywhere *says* to do it, but I'm having trouble putting it into equations that make sense for logarithmic branch points.

Everywhere says to trace a path around the branch points, with the angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ corresponding to the angles between each branch point and any given point on the path. As a circle is traced around the first branch point, $\theta_1$ gets incremented by $2\pi$, then the path is followed along the cut to the next branch point with the angles remaining the same. Then a circle is traced around the second branch point, with $\theta_2$ getting incremented by $2\pi$. Then you follow the cut back to the initial point, again with no change in angle.

If the function is single valued, you should arrive back at the same value for $f(z)$ after tracing this path. This is easy to show for something like $((z-1)(z+1))^{1/2}$ :

$$
(r_1e^{i\theta_1} \cdot r_2e^{i\theta_2})^{1/2}=r_1r_2e^{i(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2})} \\ 
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
(r_1e^{i(\theta_1+2\pi)} \cdot r_2e^{i(\theta_2+2\pi)})^{1/2}& =r_1r_2e^{i(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}+2\pi)} 
\\
&=r_1r_2e^{i(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2})}e^{i(2\pi)} 
\\
&=r_1r_2e^{i(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2})}(1)
\\
&=r_1r_2e^{i(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2})}
\end{align*}
$$

But throw in a logarithm with infinite sheets and it doesn't seem to add up, like: $\log((z-1)(z+1))$

$$
\log(r_1e^{i\theta_1} \cdot r_2e^{i\theta_2}) = \ln(r_1r_2) + i(\theta_1+\theta_2)
$$

$$
\log(r_1e^{i(\theta_1+2\pi)} \cdot r_2e^{i(\theta_2+2\pi)}) = \ln(r_1r_2) + i(\theta_1+\theta_2 +4\pi)
$$

It's no longer periodic so multiples of $2\pi$ no longer cancel out automatically.

If you set $0\leq\theta_1<2\pi$ and $-\pi\leq \theta_2 < \pi$ which i believe it is supposed to be with the additional branch point at infinity, seemingly the only way to stay single valued going from $\theta_1=0 $  to  $\theta_1=2\pi$   and simultaneously from $\theta_2=-\pi $  to  $\theta_2=\pi$ is for the trace to cross over the branch cut.

$$
\begin{align*}
\log(r_1e^{i(0)} \cdot r_2e^{i(-\pi)})& = \ln(r_1r_2) + i(-\pi) \\
\log(r_1e^{i(0+2\pi)} \cdot r_2e^{i(-\pi+2\pi)}) &= \ln(r_1r_2) + i(3\pi) &\text{ (not the same value)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\\
\log(r_1e^{i(0)} \cdot r_2e^{i(\pi)})& = \ln(r_1r_2) + i(\pi) \\
\log(r_1e^{i(0+2\pi)} \cdot r_2e^{i(\pi-2\pi)}) &= \ln(r_1r_2) + i(\pi) &\text{ (same value)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Basically it seems like one of the branch points has to be traced around the wrong direction, from  the maximum angle to the minimum angle, which corresponds to the trace crossing over the branch cut before going around the point. If you treat infinity as a single point on the Reimann sphere, tracing around the cut means both points should be gone around either clockwise or both counterclockwise, but that seems to result in extra $i\pi$'s in the value of the function.

What is going on here? I'm clearly missing something because I know this works, just every explanation I have seen is lacking some kind of information needed to describe the full idea of what they are trying to do here.

Since there seems to be some confusion, this is the method for testing a branch cut I was referring to earlier:

[Branch cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz5Sg.png)

[Associated graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj5S1.png)

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing branch points with branch cuts? (see https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/04/04/ and https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/04/05/)

Comment: the difference between the two functions is that infinity is a pole (not a branch point) for the square root one but still a branch point for the logarithmic one so one needs a cut there too in that case

Comment: I am specifically talking about the branch cuts you create using the branch points. The whole purpose is to make a multi-valued function single-valued, but how do you show that the chosen branch cut renders a single valued function? And I know infinity is a branch point, i mentioned it in the post and have the cut passing from -1 through infinity to 1.

Comment: Your question is confused. Do you know that if $U$ is simply connected and doesn't contain any branch point then any branch of $f$ extends analytically to the whole of $U$?

Comment: @reuns I am specifically talking about multi-valued functions with multiple branch points, as I specified in my original post. What is confusing?

Comment: The very first sentence is "Everywhere says to trace a path around the branch points, with the angles θ1
 and θ2
 corresponding to the angles between each branch point and any given point on the path." What are the angles of the path? What are angles between points? In the next sentence those angles are increased, so they were not numbers but... something. That is confusing. I stopped reading there.

Comment: One has to be cautious with the terminology here. "Function" means single-valued. If someone just refers to a function, it will be a "single-valued function". "Multi-valued functions" are not truly functions. Cauchy's theorem and integral formula, and the result that reuns quoted which follows from them, are all about functions, not multi-valued functions. If you restrict a multi-valued function to a simply-connected domain, and choose a particular value for it at one point in that domain, it automatically uniquely determines the value everywhere in that domain, making it single-valued.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can actually draw some pictures and clear up your confusion.
$f(z) = \log(z^2-1)$ has three branch points where it is not analytic: $z=1, z=-1, z=\infty$.

In order to make $f$ single-valued, we need to restrict it to a simply-connected domain on the Riemann sphere. We can do that by connecting the three branch points by a simple curve, and discarding that curve from the domain of $f$. While any simple curve would work, it is almost always easiest to use lines:

[image]

In this example, $1$ is connected to $-1$, and $-1$ is further connected to $\infty$. The domain $U$ consisting of all the Riemann sphere outside this curve is simply-connected. We can choose a particular value for $f$ at some point not on $(-\infty, 1]$, say $f(\sqrt{e + 1}) = 1$. Then take the Taylor series of $f$ about this point, having the selected value as constant term, and arrive at a single-valued function within the radius of convergence. Then per the result reuns quoted, extend that function to the entirety of $U$, on which by Cauchy's theorem it will be single-valued, since $f'$ is analytic everywhere in $U$ and thus will integrate to $0$ around any closed loop.

Now, let's add your path description:

[image]

I hope you can see why that didn't work. The whole point of cut lines is that they are removed from the domain of the function. You cannot cross them. When you cross the cut, the value of the function jumps discontinuously, which you ignored.

If you want examine it properly, you have to also draw a circle around the third branch point, $\infty$. When projected into the plane, a small counter-clockwise circle about $\infty$ becomes a large clockwise circle about $0$, which encircles both of the other branch points.

[image]